# Changing colours for button which have got a focus

Tags: dotnetbar

I use DotNetBar controls. I can change colours for buttons with:

```
Office2007ColorTable table = ((Office2007Renderer)GlobalManager.Renderer).ColorTable;
Office2007ButtonItemColorTable bt = table.ButtonItemColors[6];
bt.Default.Background = new LinearGradientColorTable(Color.White);
bt.MouseOver.Background = new LinearGradientColorTable(Color.Green);
```

Unfortunate I cannot find how I can change colour for a focused button.
Is it possible?